# Ошибка jQuery - SyntaxError: missing ; before statement после перехода на https

Tags: jquery, ssl, сертификат, letsencrypt

Через cPanel установил бесплатный **SSL сертификат Let's Encrypt**.

Поправил все пути - поменял с http на https. Перенастроил редиректы в htaccess.

РЕЗУЛЬТАТ: сайт стал защищённым - **HTTPS**

**ПРОБЛЕМА** такая: сама библиотека **jQuery стала ругаться и выдавать ошибку "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement"**. Была версия 1.8.2. Поставил последнюю с CDN - 3.1.1. Ставил ранние версии... Ошибка не ушла.
С футера закидывал в хедер, выше всех остальных библиотек. То же самое всё.
Код такой:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Прошу помочь решить проблему.

Comment: А если выключить все другие скрипты на странице, то проблема останется?

Comment: Отключил остальные скрипты. jQuery заработал, ошибка ушла, и даже сработала функция hide/show. Но теперь crossSlide ругается - TypeError: $ is not a function

Comment: значит проблема в них. Включайте по одному и узнаете где искать.

Comment: проблема странная.

есть один большой общий скрипт all.js, где хранится около десяти разных js-скриптов. 

Для проверки я закоментировал вставку скрипта в html коде так: <!--  ...  -->. И закоментировал все строки в самом скрипте так: //    Каждую строку отдельно. jQuery не ругается и ошибок не выдаёт. 

Но если раскомментировать скрипт в html коде <!--  ...  -->, jQuery начинает ругаться SyntaxError: missing ; before statement. Хотя весь скрипт внутри закомментирован слешами //. Что это???

Comment: поставьте в самом конце ;

Comment: нет, без изменений всё равно